# Supremum and convergence theorem

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, supremum-and-infimum

I have two easy question but that I'd like to be sure of the answer:

$1)$ when you are looking at the supremum of a r.v. so defined: $$\sup_{t\in \mathbb R}X_t$$
the supremum is over the real number excluded infinity, right?

$2)$ Can we apply the monotone convergence theorem, or Lebesgue's theorem, or Fatou's Lemma when we have the following?
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}E[|X_n|]\to E[|X|]$$
I should check that $|X_n|$ (Notice: on the absolute value of the r.v. right?) satisfy the condition of the relative theorem and then I can apply it, right?

Comment: $\infty$ is not a real number, so of course it is excluded from $\sup_{t\in\mathbb R}\cdot$. The Monotone and dominated convergence theorems would allow you to conclude that the limit of the expectations is the expectation of the limit, but only if the hypotheses of the theorem in question are satisfied.

Comment: @Math1000 but the fact that there is the absolute value inside the expectation, change it something?